# Chemfig Scheme: wrong alignement of a reaction

Tags: align, chemfig, chemistry, mhchem, chemschemex

I'm trying to use chemfig to put a reaction in my document, but the diferent molecules are missaligned. How I coul fix it?
This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mhchem}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chemfig{*6(---=--)}
\arrow{->[\ce{e^-}]}
\charge{30:4pt=$\bullet +$}{\chemleft( \chemfig{*6(---=--)} \chemright)}
\quad $\equiv$ \quad
\chemleft( \chemfig{*6(---(-[:30,0.33,,,draw=none]\oplus)-(-[2,0.33,,,draw=none]\bullet)--)} \chemright)
\quad $\equiv$ \quad
\chemleft( \chemfig{*6(---(-[:30,0.33,,,draw=none]\bullet)-(-[2,0.33,,,draw=none]\oplus)--)} \chemright)
\schemestop
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

And this is the figure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{*6(---=--)}
    \arrow{->[$\mathrm{e}^{-}$]}
    \chemleft( \chemfig{*6(---\charge{30:20pt=$\bullet +$}{}=--)} \chemright)
    \arrow{0}[,0.2]$\equiv$\arrow{0}[,0.2]
    \chemleft( \chemfig{*6(---\charge{30:4pt=$\oplus$}{}-\charge{90:4pt=$\bullet$}{}--)}~ \chemright)
    \arrow{0}[,0.2]$\equiv$\arrow{0}[,0.2]
    \chemleft( \chemfig{*6(---\charge{30:4pt=$\bullet$}{}-\charge{90:4pt=$\oplus$}{}--)}~ \chemright)
    \schemestop
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @polyn !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the new tool "QuickReaction"    [quickreaction](https://ctan.org/pkg/quickreaction?lang=en)

Quickreaction aligns the molecules, no matter where you start drawing the molecule in ChemFig;

You can place multiple lines of text above and below the arrows;

Adding the name of molecules is easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[iupac]{quickreaction}
\begin{document}
    \begin{quickreaction}
        \chemfig{*6(---=--)} \&
        \quickarrow[\ce{e^-}] \&
        \chemleft( \chemfig{*6(---=--)} \chemright{)^{\bullet +}}
        \& $\equiv$ \&
        \chemleft( \chemfig{*6(---(-[:30,0.33,,,draw=none]\oplus)-(-[2,0.33,,,draw=none]\bullet)--)} \chemright)
        \& $\equiv$ \&
        \chemleft( \chemfig{*6(---(-[:30,0.33,,,draw=none]\bullet)-(-[2,0.33,,,draw=none]\oplus)--)} \chemright) \\
    \end{quickreaction}
\end{document}
```

[image]